# Java 8 CustomizedThread::new equals new CustomizedThread()?

Tags: java, lambda, threadpool

I create Runner in two ways. But ::new doesn't work.
Then I marked the debugger point at Runner1's construct. The debugger point didn't work either.
Who can tell me why?

Is there any difference with Runnable in Runner1::new?

Here is my code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable n1 = Runner1::new;
    Runnable n2 = new Runner2();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    executorService.submit(n1);
    executorService.submit(n2);
    while (true) {

    }
}

public static class Runner1 implements Runnable {
    public Runner1() {
        System.out.println("construct 1");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello1");
    }
}

public static class Runner2 implements Runnable {
    public Runner2() {
        System.out.println("construct 2");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runnable n1 = Runner1::new` is roughly analogous to this code:

```
Runnable n1 = () -> new Runner1();
```

In other words, the `Runnable` `n1` will *instantiate* a `Runner1` *when it's called*.

That's not what you want to do, instead you want to *instantiate a `Runner1`* and assign that new `Runner1` to `n1`, just as you did with `n2`.

Using the `::new` syntax as a `Runnable` is not very useful, because a `Runnable` doesn't have a return value. In other words: your `n1` `Runnable` would *instantiate* a `Runner1` but not make it accessible to any other code.

The way `::new` is usually used is to implement something like a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) like this:

```
Supplier<List<Object>> emptyListSuppier = ArrayList::new;
```

Comment: OK, I think I got it.  () -> new Runner1(); is equals a abstract implementation like new Runnable {public void run() {new Runner1()}}  . Thnkas ,That help me a lot

Comment: Right, I see. Yeah, your rephrasing is clearer, thanks